# Phonegap/Cordova video capture produces not supported error every time on ios simmulator

Tags: ios, cordova, ios-simulator

I'm trying to test the `capture.captureVideo` function of Phonegap/Cordova on version 6.1 of the ios simulator. However, invoking that method always produces a `CaptureError.CAPTURE_NOT_SUPPORTED` error. I have added the plugin and added

```
<feature name="Capture">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVCapture" />
</feature>
```

to the `config.xml` file as prescribed by the [docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html#capture.captureVideo). Any idea whats causing the error?

Comment: You can't capture on the simulator (no camera). Have you tried on a device?

Comment: I have not yet tried on a device. `camera.getPicture` allows you to select pictures from the Camera Roll, I wish `capture.captureVideo` did a similar thing.